# Let Apache connect through a proxy

Tags: apache-2.2, proxy

I have a question to let HTTP Proxy requests via a proxy.

Here is the situation:
- I am connected from home to a VPN of my company.
- The VPN has a proxy server, which I have configured and it works correctly. I can reach all internal company URL's now.

Now I have the situation that Apache needs to retrieve a URL as well, via that same proxy. And that is where it goes wrong. The request times out. From the browser I can reach that internal URL fine, because the browser is using the proxy for its requests.

So how can I set up Apache to use a proxy?

Please note, I am not asking how to get ProxyPass working, but I am trying to make this work:

```
<Location /shared_resources_url/>
  ProxyPass http://www.internalcompanyserver.com/shared_resources_url/
  ProxyPassReverse http://www.internalcompanyserver.com/shared_resources_url/
</Location>
```

So, Apache needs to reach the internalcompanyserver.com . How do I configure Apache to use the company proxy?

I tried Googling this one of course, but I get a lot of results about ProxyPass, not about actually letting Apache connect through a proxy first.

I hope somebody understands what my question is and can help me out! :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It looks like the ProxyRemote setting might do what you desire:
http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_proxy.html#proxyremote

Comment: That's it! Thanks for the answer! :)
I configured it in this way:
ProxyRemote http://www.internalcompanyserver.com/shared_resources_url/ http://address_of_proxy:port . And it actually makes sense. I have added it in front of the ProxyPass (outside the Location element) and it works like a charm.

Answer (score 1):

(apache) in your virtualhost you can declare your web proxy :

```
ProxyRemote http http://xxxxxxx:8080
ProxyRemote https http://xxxxxxx:8080
ProxyRemote ftp http://xxxxxxx:8080
```

OR

```
ProxyRemote * http://xxxxxxx:8080
```

Otherwise, in /etc/sysconfig/httpd, you can add :

```
export http_proxy="http://xxxxxxx:8080/"
export https_proxy="http://xxxxxxx:8080/"
```

(but this applies to all virtualhosts...)

Answer (score -1):

The thing is you are expecting wrong. If you want to retrieve a url then it is done via code that runs inside apache. AFAIK, apache is for serving content not retrieving content. Retrieving content is done by either code (like php, java , etc) or tools like wget or curl. Both wget and curl very well support connecting through proxy.

Comment: I think Apache is really the one who is not routing the request correctly, in fact.. if I want to Proxy a URL with a ProxyPass, it also needs to know of the Connection Proxy, otherwise Apache can't serve the content that needs to be requested via the proxy. So in this case, I think Apache is the application that retrieves the content :)